# Excel: Overcome value error with MID

Tags: excel

I want to check if the second digit in a number is 0
Example:

```
101 --> yes
605 --> yes
234 --> no
```

I wrote this formula

```
=IF(AND(C9>100;C9<909;VALUE(MID(C9;2;1))=0);"Yes";"No")
```

when the number I'm checking is less than 12 I get a #Value error. I know it has to do with MID, but I thought that the first 2 conditions are calculated first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#Value` error come from `VALUE` function feed invalid text so it can generate valid result, good news is it can be removed in this case, but `0` must be quoted so treated as text

```
=IF(AND(C9>100;C9<909;MID(C9;2;1)="0");"Yes";"No")
```